# How to scroll view in windows 8.1 programmatically?

Tags: c#, xaml, scroll, windows-8.1

I have a windows 8.1 view:
For example:

MyPage.xaml

```
<Grid>
<Hub>
<HubSection x:Name"FirstSection">
<Button x:Name="NavigateToThirdSection" Tapped="NavigateToThirdSection_Tapped"></Button>
</HubSection>
<HubSection x:Name"SecondSection">
</HubSection>
<HubSection x:Name"ThirdSection">
<TextBlock Text="Third Section.."></TextBlock>
</HubSection>
</Hub>
</Grid>
```

MyPage.xaml.cs

```
private void StackPanel_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
//What Should I do to reach the third HubSection end of the page when I click the button at the first HubSection
}
```

I need to reach the end of the page horizontally when I click at the button at the begin of page.

Regards,

Comment: After trying I got the answer: Hub.ScrollToSection(HubSection);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all give Hubname **MainHub** or etc...

```
private void StackPanel_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //What Should I do to reach the third HubSection end of the page when I click the button at the first HubSection
    MainHub.ScrollToSection(ThirdSection);
}
```